Transform sample data from different populations to increase sample size
I have n = 6 for each of six different normal distributions with different means and possibly same (or similar) stdev.  So the distributions have similar shape with different position of center.  I want to estimate 10th percentile with a LCB from each distribution, but n = 6 yields a terribly low confidence level.
If I standardize the data so all 36 values are now distributed N(0,1) and find a point estimate for 10th percentile (and lower confidence bound),  can I then "un"standardize those values back to each of the original distributions AND retain the increased confidence by having n = 36 for the transformed data?  Or does each estimate still only have the confidence from n = 6?


I'm guessing LCB = lower confidence bound? If so, please spell it out on first use.  2. "If I standardize the data so all 36 values are now distributed N(0,1)" -- If you're standardizing by sample quantities rather than population quantities, no they won't be standard normal, nor even independent. Is the intent to use different estimates of sample means but a single estimate of $\sigma$?


Glen,  I am new to posting in this forum and it appears I did not provide a way to edit the post when posting as a guest.  You are correct in that LCB is lower confidence bound.  Sorry about that.    I used the sample mean since it should be unbiased.  I could use the population stdev since I believe I know what it is and that is is about the same for each population.  Only the means differ.
